# How do you multiply text in Emmet?

Tags: html, emmet

How do you multiply text in Emmet? For example,

```
div{Some Text} where Some Text repeats in div
div{Some Text*3} and div{Some Text}*3 do not work.
```

should output

```
<div>
    Some Text
    Some Text
    Some Text
</div>
```

Comment: Don't think so you can multiply text in emmet. Emmet is used for only CSS properties and HTML tags

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with curly brackets: `{Some Text}`:

```
ul>li*5{this is a list item!}
```

results in:

```
<ul>
    <li>this is a list item!</li>
    <li>this is a list item!</li>
    <li>this is a list item!</li>
    <li>this is a list item!</li>
    <li>this is a list item!</li>
</ul>
```

But for your example where you don't want to duplicate the div element, use:

```
div>{Some Text}*3
```

This explicitly creates "Some Text" 3 times inside 1 div.